# Script running only on Webserver and not locally

Tags: javascript, html, webserver

I’ve already tried to search this but came
up with no explanation.

I don‘t want to post any code.

My question is:
I have code which includes JavaScript. The code is working fine on my Webserver which is hosted by some German provider. The same code is not working on my local Webserver.

What could be the reason? I get the same errors in the console on both servers.

I’d appreciate any kind answer.

Comment: I don't want to post any answer if you don't want to post code, or errors or anything we can use

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask].

Comment: It would really help us if you added a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I can’t add code since there is sensitive data